# Comparing nested dictionaries into general dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, comparison

I would like to compare multiple nested dictionaries inside a larger dictionary. Suppose we have the following dictionary:

```
pricesDict = { "supermarket_1": {"apples": 1, "bananas": 2, "melons": 3},
               "supermarket_2": {"apples": 1.5, "bananas": 2, "melons": 3},
               "supermarket_3": {"apples": 1, "bananas": 2, "melons": 3},
               "supermarket_4": {"apples": 1, "bananas": 2.7, "melons": 3}}
```

I have a `pricesDict` that contains the prices of some products (more than 3 as shown above) in different supermarkets (more than 4 as shown above).

I want to go through it to compare the nested supermarkets with one another (e.g `supermarket_1` with `supermarket_2`, `supermarket_3` and `supermarket_4`, `supermarket_2` with `supermarket_3` and `supermarket_4` and so on) to find out which one has the lowest prices.

If the programme spots a difference between the price of a specific product in two supermarkets it should print a message to inform us that there is a difference on the prices.

The output should be something like the following:

```
There is a price difference between supermarket_1: 1 and supermarket_2: 1.5 in apples
There is a price difference between supermarket_1: 2 and supermarket_4: 2.7 in bananas
There is a price difference between supermarket_2: 1.5 and supermarket_3: 1 in apples
There is a price difference between supermarket_2: 1.5 and supermarket_4: 1 in apples
There is a price difference between supermarket_2: 2 and supermarket_4: 2.7 in bananas
There is a price difference between supermarket_3: 2 and supermarket_4: 2.7 in bananas
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with `itertools.combinations` and a nested loop:

```
from itertools import combinations

for first_market, second_market in combinations(pricesDict, 2):
    for produce in ["apples", "bananas", "melons"]:
        first_price = pricesDict[first_market][produce]
        second_price = pricesDict[second_market][produce]
        
        if first_price != second_price:
            print(
                  f"There is a price difference between {first_market}: {first_price} " +
                  f"and {second_market}: {second_price} in {produce}"
                 )
```

this prints:

```
There is a price difference between supermarket_1: 1 and supermarket_2: 1.5 in apples
There is a price difference between supermarket_1: 2 and supermarket_4: 2.7 in bananas
There is a price difference between supermarket_2: 1.5 and supermarket_3: 1 in apples
There is a price difference between supermarket_2: 1.5 and supermarket_4: 1 in apples
There is a price difference between supermarket_2: 2 and supermarket_4: 2.7 in bananas
There is a price difference between supermarket_3: 2 and supermarket_4: 2.7 in bananas
```

Comment: what if there are more than 3 products e.g. 1000 products and i can not list them all as you did in the second for loop?

Comment: @MariosAntakis in that case, you could change `["apples", "bananas", "melons"]` to `[k for k in pricesDict["supermarket_1"]]`, assuming every market has the same products in your dict

Answer (score 1):

Adding to [hhmiko's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73693223/14891756), we can create the list of all the products within the code like this assuming every nested supermarket dictionary contains the same keys as all other nested supermarket dictionaries.

```py
supermarkets = list(pricesDict.keys())
items = list(pricesDict[supermarkets[0]].keys())
```

and substitute the items list in line 4 of her answer